# nvd3 - Set yAxis min/max padding

Tags: nvd3.js

Is there any way to set the min and max values to go a bit further than the min/max of the data?

I would like to prevent the max value to be in the chart's limit, like in this image:

[image]

As you can see, the max is 255.00 and when the line is at that value, it kinda stays in the chart border. I would like to set the chart to have a small padding on that area.

Thanks